# Introspection on a python decorated method

Tags: python, decorator, introspection, inspect

I need to do some introspection on a decorated method in python 2.7. Usually I use `getattr(my_module, 'my_method')` but the following case returns me the outer function of my decorator.

In *my_module.py*

```
def my_decorator(function):
    def outer():
        return function()
    return outer

@my_decorator
def my_method():
    pass
```

Now in a shell:

```
>>> import my_module
>>> getattr(my_module, 'my_method')
<function outer at 0x7f46958aa668>
```

How can I actually get the function that interests me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the undecorated functon by introspecting the `my_method.__closure__` attribute (in Python3) or `my_method.func_closure` (in Python2):

```
def my_decorator(function):
    def outer():
        print('outer')
        return function()
    return outer

@my_decorator
def my_method():
    print('inner')

try:
    # Python2
    my_method.func_closure[0].cell_contents()
except AttributeError:
    # Python3
    my_method.__closure__[0].cell_contents()
```

prints

```
inner
```